# MaterialSkin Cross-Thread operation not valid - despite delegate

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm building a semi-dynamic UI based on a TableLayoutPanel.  I can dynamically update settings to change the Row, Column & Span of a given control.  I have a timer that watches for settings changes and drives the UI changes, so I have a delegate to handle the cross thread call.

```
private delegate void tableLayoutDelegate(TableLayoutPanel panel, Control control, int row, int column, int rowSpan, int columnSpan);
public static void SafeUpdateTableLayout(TableLayoutPanel panel, Control control, int row, int column, int rowSpan, int columnSpan)
{
    //if (panel.InvokeRequired || control.InvokeRequired)
    if (panel.InvokeRequired)
    {
        tableLayoutDelegate _delegate = new tableLayoutDelegate(SafeUpdateTableLayout);
        panel.Invoke(_delegate, new object[] { panel, control, row, column, rowSpan, columnSpan });
    }
    else
    {
        panel.SetColumn(control, column);
        panel.SetRow(control, row);
        panel.SetColumnSpan(control, columnSpan);
        panel.SetRowSpan(control, rowSpan);
        panel.Refresh();
    }
}
```

This works pretty well.  I can get it to move controls, including container controls.  But then I started getting illegal cross thread operation exceptions:

> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> [External Code]  **<= This made me suspicious**
> DynamicUI.UtilityFunctions.FormControls.SafeUpdateTableLayout(System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel, System.Windows.Forms.Control, int, int, int, int) in ControlExtensions.cs

It was working fine until I added another child control, which happened to be a MaterialButton from [this MaterialSkin 2 package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MaterialSkin.2/2.3.1?_src=template).  Seeing the [External Code] portion of the call stack made me think that it is a problem in the code that is executing in the MaterialSkin DLL.  A bit more testing showed that it only occurs if I try to anchor that button in its parent (which is a MaterialCard from the same package, incidentally), and only if I try to anchor it to the right.

So... If I am correct in my diagnosis, is there any way to fix it?  I tried checking for InvokeRequired on the Control as well as the Panel, but that didn't help.  Any other ideas, or do I just avoid anchoring MaterialButton controls to the right, and then try to dynamically move them!

Comment: The [code](https://github.com/leocb/MaterialSkin/blob/master/MaterialSkin/Controls/MaterialButton.cs) for `MaterialButton` in the [MaterialSkin package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MaterialSkin.2/2.3.1?_src=template) looks pretty error-prone - lots of on-the-fly event/delegate subscriptions to singletons; UI events that appear to be unsubscribed and more importantly there's alot of unknown follow-on affects due to the way the code is taking a reactive stance to things.  It's generally bad for UI code to perform operations (particularly events) immediately when say changing a property...

Comment: ...because it's not obvious to the caller whether performing a seemingly innocent operation will require a certain threading environment.  I see you have already raised a [ticket](https://github.com/leocb/MaterialSkin/issues/322) on GitHub.  That is a good fallback in the event no solution is found here.   I noticed it has quite a few issues too.  Good luck!